# Energy of compound harmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

Consider two harmonic oscillators of masses $m_1,m_2$ and spring constants $k_1,k_2$ respectively. Their motions are described by equations $$u_1=A_1\sin(\omega t+\varphi_1),\qquad u_2=A_2\sin(\omega t+\varphi_2).$$
Total mechanical energies of these two are given by $$E_1=\frac12k_1A_1^2,\qquad E_2=\frac12k_2A_2^2.$$ What can be said about energy $E$ of the compound harmonic oscillator $u=u_1+u_2$? In particular, is it true that $$E=E_1+E_2?$$ What if $\omega_1\neq\omega_2$ (in which case $u$ isn't harmonic or even periodic)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you defining $E_1$ and $E_2$?

Comment: u1+u2 makes no sense, the same as you have two masses m one  m1 going with velocity  v1=am/s,  and one  m2 going with v2=b m/s, s1(t)+s2(t) is not meaningful  but there Energie E1+E2 can be calculated.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I added that to the question.

Comment: @trula by $u_1+u_2$ I simply mean a (harmonic) motion that is described by the sum of those two sine curves, from mathematical point of view I do not see a problem, perhaps some wording is unclear?

Comment: Make sure to proofread your question to avoid confusion. I see at least one subscript that seems to be mismatched.

Comment: @byk7 if the oscillators are coupled then the frequencies of oscillations are not the frequencies of the uncoupled oscillators…

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just the mathematical addition
$u1+u2=A(sin(\omega t+\phi_1)+sin(\omega t+\phi_2)=B*(sin(\omega t+\phi_3)$ you have $B=A*\sqrt{((sin(\phi_1)+sin(phi_2)^2+(cos(\phi_1)+cos(\phi_2))^2))}$
and $\phi_3=\arctan(\frac{sin(\phi_1)+sin(phi_2)}{cos(\phi_1)+cos(\phi_2)}$ so the energie is not added, bu the system is just another oscillator, not a physical composition of movements.